# crear un objeto nuevo a partir de otro

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, objeto, react-hooks

estoy trabajando con react, es un componente funcional q recibe como `props` una lista, es algo como esto:

```
[{count: 3, type: 'tipo1', values: ['valor1','valor2','valor3']},
{count: 4, type: 'tipo2', values: ['valor4','valor5','valor6','valor7,]},
{count: 2, type: 'tipo3', values: ['valor8','valor9']}]
```

Para hacer lo q quiero necesito q el objeto este de esta forma:

```
[{type: 'tipo1', value:'valor1'},
{type: 'tipo1', value: 'valor2'},
{type: 'tipo1', value: 'valor3'},
{type: 'tipo2', value: 'valor4'},
{type: 'tipo2', value: 'valor5'},
{type: 'tipo2', value: 'valor6'},
{type: 'tipo2', value: 'valor7'},
{type: 'tipo3', value: 'valor8'},
{type: 'tipo3', value: 'valor9'}]
```

El `count` no me importa mucho xq no lo uso como tal en esta parte, mi confusion esta en como pasar del objeto original al objeto nuevo q necesito ya sea usando reactHooks o solo js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es muy fácil de hacer usando [`Array.ptototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), esto si quieres hacerlo en una sola línea, así el archivo es menos pesado pero también menos comprensible, pero si prefieres hacerlo paso a paso, puedes usar [`Array.ptototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Aquí te dejo las dos formas que yo veo para hacerlo

```js
const array1 = [{count: 3, type: 'tipo1', values: ['valor1','valor2','valor3']},
{count: 4, type: 'tipo2', values: ['valor4','valor5','valor6','valor7',]},
{count: 2, type: 'tipo3', values: ['valor8','valor9']}];
const array2 = []; // Copia

array1.map(el => [el.values.forEach(value => array2.push({type:el.type, value})), el][1])
console.log(array2);
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos es recorrer el array, ya que el prototipo `map` cambia los elementos del array con lo que se le devuelva, vamos a crear un array de dos elementos, en el primero vamos a recorrer el array y vamos a poner nuevos elementos al otro array que será la copia con `push`, en el segundo el elemento por defecto, seguido a esto devolvemos el segundo elemento del array haciendo que el principal no se modifique.

La otra forma es prácticamente lo mismo, pero más larga.

```js
const array1 = [{count: 3, type: 'tipo1', values: ['valor1','valor2','valor3']},
{count: 4, type: 'tipo2', values: ['valor4','valor5','valor6','valor7',]},
{count: 2, type: 'tipo3', values: ['valor8','valor9']}];
const array2 = []; // Copia

array1.forEach(el => {
  el.values.forEach(value => {
    const {type} = el;
    array2.push({type, value})
  });
});
console.log(array2)
```

Recorremos también el array, pero esta vez es una forma más legible, como podrás ver.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tu respuesta me ayudo mucho! 